Is there a way to programmatically pull a pool ID using two tokens CA?
Is there a way to use the Raydium SDK to find a pool? From what I've seen I cannot find this information.

Raydium has several products, so it depends. But if you are looking for the CLMM pool, it looks like you can use getPdaPoolId.
I tried this to see if I could find a BONK/USDC pool ID. Keep in mind that you many need to try each mint address first.
import {
    getPdaPoolId,
} from "@raydium-io/raydium-sdk";
import {PublicKey} from "@solana/web3.js";
(async () => {
    const {publicKey: poolId} = await getPdaPoolId(
        new PublicKey("CAMMCzo5YL8w4VFF8KVHrK22GGUsp5VTaW7grrKgrWqK"), // CLMM address
        new PublicKey("E64NGkDLLCdQ2yFNPcavaKptrEgmiQaNykUuLC1Qgwyp"), // Config address
        new PublicKey("DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263"), // BONK mint
        new PublicKey("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v") // USDC mint
        );
    console.log(poolId.toBase58());
})();

